# Некий аналог регулярных выражений

Tags: php

Приветствую всех вошедших

Собственно есть миллион регулярок в интернете. Устраивают так себе. Придставьте вам нужно проверить 'Имя'. Ну допустим Там должно быть минимум 2 знака по английски.

1. Человек хотел ввести - 'my', а ввел - 'm.y'. Регулярка ест-но ничего не найдет. Можно ли как то на выходе в переменной получить только буквы? и проверить их 2 или больше? ( 'my'.. юзер френдли так сказать )
2. Ну или взять email. Тут веселее. Допустим человек хочет ввести email123@site.ru, а ввел - email123@siЫte.ru. Я ж незнаю рабочий это емайл или нет. Да и черт с ним. Да и пользователь не обязательно взломщик. Но вот допустим нужно простить дурака, и на выходе получить переменную с обработанным емайлом, и уже это проверить.

т.е. как сделать:

```
переменная -> выкидываем_лишнее -> if(регулярка ?){все_ок}else{что_то_не_так} ?
```

Comment: вам бы выспаться и забыть эту мысль,   ну и про регулярные выражения почитать...всего не угдаеашь :)

Comment: > переменная -> выкидываем_лишнее ...

А может по другой схеме:

> юзер набирает текст -> проверяется каждый вводимый символ (JS) -> if(что-то_лишнее) alert('Хьюстон! У нас проблемы!');

Comment: Данные не всегда вводятся. Иногда получаются из другого места. Так, что JS не катит. Вот как то нужно посимвольно процедить переменные

Comment: @frank, тогда то самое "место" должно заниматься валидацией в динамике, а вы - принять или отклонить полученный результат, и не обращать внимания на то: сделал юзверь очепятку или нет.

Comment: Иногда юзер может заполнять 'то самое' на бумаге.., а потом уже скан -> бд, и т.д. вот собственно и спросил

Comment: @frank, игра не сто́ит свечь. Девять раз, вы правильно почистите данные, а из-за того, что, как правильно заметил @eicto, "*всего не угдаеашь*", на десятый раз - удалите то, что удалению не подлежало. И вероятней всего, что ваших ошибок в этом, будет больше, чем тех пользователей, которые опечатались.

Comment: Имя? Минимум два знака по-английски? [Ха-ха-ха](http://habrahabr.ru/post/146901/).

Comment: @VladD - возможно Li = Ли. Китайское имя. Извращение, но чем черт не шутит ))

Comment: @mixalef: Бывают и однобуквенные имена. Кроме того, русские имена не укладываются в ASCII, да и английские тоже (древнее _Gráinne Ní Mháille_, например). Бывает по нескольку имён, в каком-нибудь испанском, как их вводить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмм.. если кто упростит эту конструкцию - буду благодарен. Вообщем суть такова: берем значение на входе, пропускаем через замену. Получаем значение на выходе состоящее из тех знаков которые нужны. Ну а дальше мучайте переменную проверкой регулярками

- это искали?

  ```
  $zamena = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMёйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюЁЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮ@. ";
  $input = preg_replace('/[^'.preg_quote($zamena).']/', '', $input);
  ```

Comment: Почитайте про символьные классы в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score 0):

Да, Вы правы, пользователи рано или поздно допустят ошибку при вводе данных. Потому нужно использовать валидаторы.  Ниже приведено несколько рекомендаций насчет корректности проверки ввода данных.

- Используйте [маску](http://javascriptools.sourceforge.net/samples/sample_mask.html) для компонентов, которые пользователь заполняет данными.
- Если не получается использовать маску, то хотя бы отлавливайте и блокируйте все нежелательные символы, а также устанавливайте верхний и нижний лимит длинны вводимого текста. Например: ошибки email123@site.ru => email123@siЫte.ru возникнуть не должно, если   установить границы длины 3-256, проверять на наличие символа "@" и разрешить вводить только буквы латинского алфавита, цифры 0-9 и некоторые символы ASCII (33, 35–39, 42, 43, 45, 47, 61, 63, 64, 94–96, 123–126) и точку.
- При разработке мультиязычного веб-портала учитывайте региональные стандарты, например форматирование времени и работу с денежными единицами.
- Не пытайтесь заменить выпадающие списки текстовыми полями ввода. Очень часто вижу эту ошибку. Если выпадающий список содержит огромное количество вариантов, то требуется реализовать ввод с автодополнением и функцию поиска.

Естественно, речь идет про front-end. Наша задача тут сделать работу пользователя максимально комфортной и свести к минимуму количество ошибок. В целях безопасности в реализации back-end необходимо создать повторную, более жесткую проверку данных, получаемых сервером.

---

Насчет попыток самому исправить ошибки пользователя. Эта идея в корне неверна и нерациональна. Она трудна в реализации (нужно задействовать AI, словари и многие другие вещи), при реализации можно наткнуть на еще большее количество проблем, да и вообще разрешив вводить пользователю что-угодно Вы только собьете его с толку.